# Can someone explain why elif is being ignored?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm very new to programming can't wrap my head around why my elif statements are being ignored. Can anyone help?

```
prompt = ("Enter your age to buy a ticket ")
prompt += ("or type 'quit' to end the program:")

while True:
    age = raw_input(prompt)

    if age == 'quit':
        break
    elif age < 3:
        print "Free ticket."
    elif age < 12:
        print "$10 ticket."
    else:
        print"$15 ticket."
```

Comment: `age` is a string, you will need to conver it to int with `int(age)`

Comment: And you need to do that conversion after you do the `'quit'` test. So you'll need to break that `if` up into 2 `if`s.

Comment: Thank you this fixed it, knew it would be something simple like that.

Comment: BTW, Python automatically concatenates adjacent string literals, and it lets expressions inside parentheses (or brackets or braces) span multiple lines. So you can simplfy that long `prompt` assignment to `prompt = ("Enter your age to buy a ticket "` `"or type 'quit' to end the program:")`

Comment: Also, since you're just starting you should be learning Python 3. Python 2 reaches its End Of Life in 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`age` is a string. Convert it to an int before checking for integers.

```
prompt = ("Enter your age to buy a ticket ")
prompt += ("or type 'quit' to end the program:")

while True:
    age = raw_input(prompt)

    if age == 'quit':
        break
    elif int(age) < 3:
        print "Free ticket."
    elif int(age) < 12:
        print "$10 ticket."
    else:
        print "$15 ticket."
```

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you some basic debug skills.

You want to know why `elif` is ignored means you want to know why `elif` block is not entered. And the reason is obvious, condition is `False`.

So you can simply output the condition to checkout. `print age < 3`, and it will output `False`.